# How can I clean up my anaconda base environment? (e.g., I don't need astropy, statsmodels, and ~400 other packages)

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, package, conda

**How can I just uninstall all of the non-essential packages and reinstall what I need?** By essential, I'm referring to just enough to run command line `conda` software so I can build my base environment additively (No GUI necessary).

I've been trying to install `mamba` in my base environment and it's taking hours b/c of all these package conflicts.

```
conda activate base && conda list
# packages in environment at /home/jespinoz/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0            py39h06a4308_1
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       1_gnu
aiohttp                   3.8.1            py39h7f8727e_1
aiosignal                 1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
alabaster                 0.7.12             pyhd3eb1b0_0
anaconda                  2022.05                  py39_0
anaconda-client           1.9.0            py39h06a4308_0
anaconda-navigator        2.1.4            py39h06a4308_0
anaconda-project          0.10.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
anyio                     3.5.0            py39h06a4308_0
appdirs                   1.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
argon2-cffi               21.3.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0           py39h7f8727e_0
arrow                     1.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
astroid                   2.6.6            py39h06a4308_0
astropy                   5.0.4            py39hce1f21e_0
asttokens                 2.0.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
async-timeout             4.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
atomicwrites              1.4.0                      py_0
attrs                     21.4.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
automat                   20.2.0                     py_0
autopep8                  1.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
babel                     2.9.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backports                 1.1                pyhd3eb1b0_0
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backports.tempfile        1.0                pyhd3eb1b0_1
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1
bcrypt                    3.2.0            py39he8ac12f_0
beautifulsoup4            4.11.1           py39h06a4308_0
binaryornot               0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_1
bitarray                  2.4.1            py39h7f8727e_0
bkcharts                  0.2              py39h06a4308_0
black                     19.10b0                    py_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    4.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
blosc                     1.21.0               h8c45485_0
bokeh                     2.4.2            py39h06a4308_0
boto3                     1.21.32            pyhd3eb1b0_0
botocore                  1.24.32            pyhd3eb1b0_0
bottleneck                1.3.4            py39hce1f21e_0
brotli                    1.0.9                he6710b0_2
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py39h27cfd23_1003
brunsli                   0.1                  h2531618_0
bz2file                   0.98             py39h06a4308_1
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7b6447c_0
c-ares                    1.18.1               h7f8727e_0
ca-certificates           2022.3.29            h06a4308_1
cachetools                4.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
certifi                   2021.10.8        py39h06a4308_2
cffi                      1.15.0           py39hd667e15_1
cfitsio                   3.470                hf0d0db6_6
chardet                   4.0.0           py39h06a4308_1003
charls                    2.2.0                h2531618_0
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
click                     8.0.4            py39h06a4308_0
cloudpickle               2.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
clyent                    1.2.2            py39h06a4308_1
colorama                  0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
colorcet                  2.0.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda                     4.13.0           py39h06a4308_0
conda-build               3.21.8           py39h06a4308_2
conda-content-trust       0.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1
conda-pack                0.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-package-handling    1.8.1            py39h7f8727e_0
conda-repo-cli            1.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-token               0.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1
constantly                15.1.0             pyh2b92418_0
cookiecutter              1.7.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
cryptography              3.4.8            py39hd23ed53_0
cssselect                 1.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
curl                      7.82.0               h7f8727e_0
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
cython                    0.29.28          py39h295c915_0
cytoolz                   0.11.0           py39h27cfd23_0
daal4py                   2021.5.0         py39h78b71dc_0
dal                       2021.5.1           h06a4308_803
dask                      2022.2.1           pyhd3eb1b0_0
dask-core                 2022.2.1           pyhd3eb1b0_0
dataclasses               0.8                pyh6d0b6a4_7
datashader                0.13.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
datashape                 0.5.4            py39h06a4308_1
dbus                      1.13.18              hb2f20db_0
debugpy                   1.5.1            py39h295c915_0
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
diff-match-patch          20200713           pyhd3eb1b0_0
distributed               2022.2.1           pyhd3eb1b0_0
docutils                  0.17.1           py39h06a4308_1
entrypoints               0.4              py39h06a4308_0
et_xmlfile                1.1.0            py39h06a4308_0
executing                 0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
expat                     2.4.4                h295c915_0
filelock                  3.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
flake8                    3.9.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
flask                     1.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
fontconfig                2.13.1               h6c09931_0
fonttools                 4.25.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
freetype                  2.11.0               h70c0345_0
frozenlist                1.2.0            py39h7f8727e_0
fsspec                    2022.2.0           pyhd3eb1b0_0
future                    0.18.2           py39h06a4308_1
genopype                  2021.8.18                  py_0    jolespin
gensim                    4.1.2            py39h295c915_0
giflib                    5.2.1                h7b6447c_0
glib                      2.69.1               h4ff587b_1
glob2                     0.7                pyhd3eb1b0_0
gmp                       6.2.1                h2531618_2
gmpy2                     2.1.2            py39heeb90bb_0
google-api-core           1.25.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
google-auth               1.33.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
google-cloud-core         1.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
google-cloud-storage      1.31.0                     py_0
google-crc32c             1.1.2            py39h27cfd23_0
google-resumable-media    1.3.1              pyhd3eb1b0_1
googleapis-common-protos  1.53.0           py39h06a4308_0
greenlet                  1.1.1            py39h295c915_0
grpcio                    1.42.0           py39hce63b2e_0
gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               h8213a91_2
gstreamer                 1.14.0               h28cd5cc_2
h5py                      3.6.0            py39ha0f2276_0
hdf5                      1.10.6               hb1b8bf9_0
heapdict                  1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
holoviews                 1.14.8             pyhd3eb1b0_0
hvplot                    0.7.3              pyhd3eb1b0_1
hyperlink                 21.0.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
icu                       58.2                 he6710b0_3
idna                      3.3                pyhd3eb1b0_0
imagecodecs               2021.8.26        py39h4cda21f_0
imageio                   2.9.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
imagesize                 1.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
importlib-metadata        4.11.3           py39h06a4308_0
importlib_metadata        4.11.3               hd3eb1b0_0
incremental               21.3.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
inflection                0.5.1            py39h06a4308_0
iniconfig                 1.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
intake                    0.6.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
intel-openmp              2021.4.0          h06a4308_3561
intervaltree              3.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
ipykernel                 6.9.1            py39h06a4308_0
ipython                   8.2.0            py39h06a4308_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
ipywidgets                7.6.5              pyhd3eb1b0_1
isort                     5.9.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
itemadapter               0.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
itemloaders               1.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_1
itsdangerous              2.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jdcal                     1.4.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jedi                      0.18.1           py39h06a4308_1
jeepney                   0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jinja2                    2.11.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0
jinja2-time               0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3
jmespath                  0.10.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
joblib                    1.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jpeg                      9e                   h7f8727e_0
jq                        1.6               h27cfd23_1000
json5                     0.9.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jsonschema                4.4.0            py39h06a4308_0
jupyter                   1.0.0            py39h06a4308_7
jupyter_client            6.1.12             pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyter_console           6.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyter_core              4.9.2            py39h06a4308_0
jupyter_server            1.13.5             pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyterlab                3.3.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0
jupyterlab_server         2.10.3             pyhd3eb1b0_1
jupyterlab_widgets        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
jxrlib                    1.1                  h7b6447c_2
keyring                   23.4.0           py39h06a4308_0
kiwisolver                1.3.2            py39h295c915_0
krb5                      1.19.2               hac12032_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.6.0            py39h27cfd23_0
lcms2                     2.12                 h3be6417_0
ld_impl_linux-64          2.35.1               h7274673_9
lerc                      3.0                  h295c915_0
libaec                    1.0.4                he6710b0_1
libarchive                3.4.2                h62408e4_0
libcrc32c                 1.1.1                he6710b0_2
libcurl                   7.82.0               h0b77cf5_0
libdeflate                1.8                  h7f8727e_5
libedit                   3.1.20210910         h7f8727e_0
libev                     4.33                 h7f8727e_1
libffi                    3.3                  he6710b0_2
libgcc-ng                 9.3.0               h5101ec6_17
libgfortran-ng            7.5.0               ha8ba4b0_17
libgfortran4              7.5.0               ha8ba4b0_17
libgomp                   9.3.0               h5101ec6_17
libidn2                   2.3.2                h7f8727e_0
liblief                   0.11.5               h295c915_1
libllvm11                 11.1.0               h3826bc1_1
libnghttp2                1.46.0               hce63b2e_0
libpng                    1.6.37               hbc83047_0
libprotobuf               3.19.1               h4ff587b_0
libsodium                 1.0.18               h7b6447c_0
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h2531618_0
libssh2                   1.10.0               h8f2d780_0
libstdcxx-ng              9.3.0               hd4cf53a_17
libtiff                   4.2.0                h85742a9_0
libunistring              0.9.10               h27cfd23_0
libuuid                   1.0.3                h7f8727e_2
libwebp                   1.2.2                h55f646e_0
libwebp-base              1.2.2                h7f8727e_0
libxcb                    1.14                 h7b6447c_0
libxml2                   2.9.12               h03d6c58_0
libxslt                   1.1.34               hc22bd24_0
libzopfli                 1.0.3                he6710b0_0
llvmlite                  0.38.0           py39h4ff587b_0
locket                    0.2.1            py39h06a4308_2
lxml                      4.8.0            py39h1f438cf_0
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h295c915_1
lzo                       2.10                 h7b6447c_2
markdown                  3.3.4            py39h06a4308_0
markupsafe                2.0.1            py39h27cfd23_0
matplotlib                3.5.1            py39h06a4308_1
matplotlib-base           3.5.1            py39ha18d171_1
matplotlib-inline         0.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_2
mccabe                    0.6.1            py39h06a4308_1
mistune                   0.8.4           py39h27cfd23_1000
mkl                       2021.4.0           h06a4308_640
mkl-service               2.4.0            py39h7f8727e_0
mkl_fft                   1.3.1            py39hd3c417c_0
mkl_random                1.2.2            py39h51133e4_0
mock                      4.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
mpc                       1.1.0                h10f8cd9_1
mpfr                      4.0.2                hb69a4c5_1
mpi                       1.0                       mpich
mpich                     3.3.2                hc856adb_0
mpmath                    1.2.1            py39h06a4308_0
msgpack-python            1.0.2            py39hff7bd54_1
multidict                 5.2.0            py39h7f8727e_2
multipledispatch          0.6.0            py39h06a4308_0
munkres                   1.1.4                      py_0
mypy_extensions           0.4.3            py39h06a4308_1
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py39_1
nbclassic                 0.3.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
nbclient                  0.5.13           py39h06a4308_0
nbconvert                 6.4.4            py39h06a4308_0
nbformat                  5.3.0            py39h06a4308_0
ncurses                   6.3                  h7f8727e_2
nest-asyncio              1.5.5            py39h06a4308_0
networkx                  2.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
nltk                      3.7                pyhd3eb1b0_0
nose                      1.3.7           pyhd3eb1b0_1008
notebook                  6.4.8            py39h06a4308_0
numba                     0.55.1           py39h51133e4_0
numexpr                   2.8.1            py39h6abb31d_0
numpy                     1.21.5           py39he7a7128_1
numpy-base                1.21.5           py39hf524024_1
numpydoc                  1.2                pyhd3eb1b0_0
olefile                   0.46               pyhd3eb1b0_0
oniguruma                 6.9.7.1              h27cfd23_0
openjpeg                  2.4.0                h3ad879b_0
openpyxl                  3.0.9              pyhd3eb1b0_0
openssl                   1.1.1n               h7f8727e_0
packaging                 21.3               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pandas                    1.4.2            py39h295c915_0
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
panel                     0.13.0           py39h06a4308_0
param                     1.12.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
parsel                    1.6.0            py39h06a4308_0
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
partd                     1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
patchelf                  0.13                 h295c915_0
pathlib2                  2.3.6            py39h06a4308_2
pathspec                  0.7.0                      py_0
patsy                     0.5.2            py39h06a4308_1
pcre                      8.45                 h295c915_0
pep8                      1.7.1            py39h06a4308_0
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
pigz                      2.6                  h27826a3_0    conda-forge
pillow                    9.0.1            py39h22f2fdc_0
pip                       21.2.4           py39h06a4308_0
pkginfo                   1.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
plotly                    5.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pluggy                    1.0.0            py39h06a4308_1
poyo                      0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
prometheus_client         0.13.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.20             pyhd3eb1b0_0
prompt_toolkit            3.0.20               hd3eb1b0_0
protego                   0.1.16                     py_0
protobuf                  3.19.1           py39h295c915_0
psutil                    5.8.0            py39h27cfd23_1
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pv                        1.6.6                h470a237_0    conda-forge
py                        1.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
py-lief                   0.11.5           py39h295c915_1
pyasn1                    0.4.8              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                      py_0
pycodestyle               2.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py39h27cfd23_0
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyct                      0.4.6            py39h06a4308_0
pycurl                    7.44.1           py39h8f2d780_1
pydispatcher              2.0.5            py39h06a4308_2
pydocstyle                6.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyerfa                    2.0.0            py39h27cfd23_0
pyflakes                  2.3.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pygments                  2.11.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyhamcrest                2.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_2
pyjwt                     2.1.0            py39h06a4308_0
pylint                    2.9.6            py39h06a4308_1
pyls-spyder               0.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyodbc                    4.0.32           py39h295c915_1
pyopenssl                 21.0.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
pyparsing                 3.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py39h2531618_6
pyrsistent                0.18.0           py39heee7806_0
pysocks                   1.7.1            py39h06a4308_0
pytables                  3.6.1            py39h77479fe_1
pytest                    7.1.1            py39h06a4308_0
python                    3.9.12               h12debd9_0
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-fastjsonschema     2.15.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-libarchive-c       2.9                pyhd3eb1b0_1
python-lsp-black          1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-lsp-jsonrpc        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-lsp-server         1.2.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-slugify            5.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-snappy             0.6.0            py39h2531618_3
python_abi                3.9                      2_cp39    conda-forge
pytz                      2021.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyviz_comms               2.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pywavelets                1.3.0            py39h7f8727e_0
pyxdg                     0.27               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyyaml                    6.0              py39h7f8727e_1
pyzmq                     22.3.0           py39h295c915_2
qdarkstyle                3.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qstylizer                 0.1.10             pyhd3eb1b0_0
qt                        5.9.7                h5867ecd_1
qtawesome                 1.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qtconsole                 5.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qtpy                      2.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
queuelib                  1.5.0            py39h06a4308_0
readline                  8.1.2                h7f8727e_1
regex                     2022.3.15        py39h7f8727e_0
requests                  2.27.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
requests-file             1.5.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
ripgrep                   12.1.1                        0
rope                      0.22.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
rsa                       4.7.2              pyhd3eb1b0_1
rtree                     0.9.7            py39h06a4308_1
ruamel_yaml               0.15.100         py39h27cfd23_0
s3transfer                0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
scandir                   1.10.0             pyh5d7bf9c_3
scikit-image              0.19.2           py39h51133e4_0
scikit-learn              1.0.2            py39h51133e4_1
scikit-learn-intelex      2021.5.0         py39h06a4308_0
scipy                     1.7.3            py39hc147768_0
scrapy                    2.6.1            py39h06a4308_0
seaborn                   0.11.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
secretstorage             3.3.1            py39h06a4308_0
send2trash                1.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
service_identity          18.1.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
setuptools                61.2.0           py39h06a4308_0
sip                       4.19.13          py39h295c915_0
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
smart_open                5.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
snappy                    1.1.9                h295c915_0
sniffio                   1.2.0            py39h06a4308_1
snowballstemmer           2.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
soothsayer_utils          2022.2.9                   py_0    jolespin
sortedcollections         2.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sortedcontainers          2.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
soupsieve                 2.3.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinx                    4.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    2.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
spyder                    5.1.5            py39h06a4308_1
spyder-kernels            2.1.3            py39h06a4308_0
sqlalchemy                1.4.32           py39h7f8727e_0
sqlite                    3.38.2               hc218d9a_0
stack_data                0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
statsmodels               0.13.2           py39h7f8727e_0
sympy                     1.10.1           py39h06a4308_0
tabulate                  0.8.9            py39h06a4308_0
tbb                       2021.5.0             hd09550d_0
tbb4py                    2021.5.0         py39hd09550d_0
tblib                     1.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
tenacity                  8.0.1            py39h06a4308_0
terminado                 0.13.1           py39h06a4308_0
testpath                  0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
text-unidecode            1.3                pyhd3eb1b0_0
textdistance              4.2.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
threadpoolctl             2.2.0              pyh0d69192_0
three-merge               0.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
tifffile                  2021.7.2           pyhd3eb1b0_2
tinycss                   0.4             pyhd3eb1b0_1002
tk                        8.6.11               h1ccaba5_0
tldextract                3.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
tomli                     1.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
toolz                     0.11.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
tornado                   6.1              py39h27cfd23_0
tqdm                      4.64.0           py39h06a4308_0
traitlets                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
tree                      1.8.0                h7f98852_2    conda-forge
twisted                   22.2.0           py39h7f8727e_0
typed-ast                 1.4.3            py39h7f8727e_1
typing-extensions         4.1.1                hd3eb1b0_0
typing_extensions         4.1.1              pyh06a4308_0
tzdata                    2022a                hda174b7_0
tzlocal                   2.1              py39h06a4308_0
ujson                     5.1.0            py39h295c915_0
unidecode                 1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
unixodbc                  2.3.9                h7b6447c_0
urllib3                   1.26.9           py39h06a4308_0
w3lib                     1.21.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
watchdog                  2.1.6            py39h06a4308_0
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
webencodings              0.5.1            py39h06a4308_1
websocket-client          0.58.0           py39h06a4308_4
werkzeug                  2.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
wget                      1.21.3               h0b77cf5_0
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
widgetsnbextension        3.5.2            py39h06a4308_0
wrapt                     1.12.1           py39he8ac12f_1
wurlitzer                 3.0.2            py39h06a4308_0
xarray                    0.20.1             pyhd3eb1b0_1
xlrd                      2.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
xlsxwriter                3.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
xz                        5.2.5                h7b6447c_0
yaml                      0.2.5                h7b6447c_0
yapf                      0.31.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
yarl                      1.6.3            py39h27cfd23_0
zeromq                    4.3.4                h2531618_0
zfp                       0.5.5                h295c915_6
zict                      2.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
zipp                      3.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
zlib                      1.2.12               h7f8727e_2
zope                      1.0              py39h06a4308_1
zope.interface            5.4.0            py39h7f8727e_0
zstd                      1.4.9                haebb681_0

conda activate base && conda list | wc -l
444
```

Even my base installation had a lot going on:

```
(base) [jespinoz@login02 Plastisphere]$ conda list --revisions
2022-04-28 20:07:06  (rev 0)
    +_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf-0.1.0
    +_libgcc_mutex-0.1
    +_openmp_mutex-4.5
    +aiohttp-3.8.1
    +aiosignal-1.2.0
    +alabaster-0.7.12
    +anaconda-2022.05
    +anaconda-client-1.9.0
    +anaconda-navigator-2.1.4
    +anaconda-project-0.10.2
    +anyio-3.5.0
    +appdirs-1.4.4
    +argon2-cffi-21.3.0
    +argon2-cffi-bindings-21.2.0
    +arrow-1.2.2
    +astroid-2.6.6
    +astropy-5.0.4
    +asttokens-2.0.5
    +async-timeout-4.0.1
    +atomicwrites-1.4.0
    +attrs-21.4.0
    +automat-20.2.0
    +autopep8-1.6.0
    +babel-2.9.1
    +backcall-0.2.0
    +backports-1.1
    +backports.functools_lru_cache-1.6.4
    +backports.tempfile-1.0
    +backports.weakref-1.0.post1
    +bcrypt-3.2.0
    +beautifulsoup4-4.11.1
    +binaryornot-0.4.4
    +bitarray-2.4.1
    +bkcharts-0.2
    +black-19.10b0
    +blas-1.0
    +bleach-4.1.0
    +blosc-1.21.0
    +bokeh-2.4.2
    +boto3-1.21.32
    +botocore-1.24.32
    +bottleneck-1.3.4
    +brotli-1.0.9
    +brotlipy-0.7.0
    +brunsli-0.1
    +bzip2-1.0.8
    +c-ares-1.18.1
    +ca-certificates-2022.3.29
    +cachetools-4.2.2
    +certifi-2021.10.8
    +cffi-1.15.0
    +cfitsio-3.470
    +chardet-4.0.0
    +charls-2.2.0
    +charset-normalizer-2.0.4
    +click-8.0.4
    +cloudpickle-2.0.0
    +clyent-1.2.2
    +colorama-0.4.4
    +colorcet-2.0.6
    +conda-4.12.0
    +conda-build-3.21.8
    +conda-content-trust-0.1.1
    +conda-env-2.6.0
    +conda-pack-0.6.0
    +conda-package-handling-1.8.1
    +conda-repo-cli-1.0.4
    +conda-token-0.3.0
    +conda-verify-3.4.2
    +constantly-15.1.0
    +cookiecutter-1.7.3
    +cryptography-3.4.8
    +cssselect-1.1.0
    +curl-7.82.0
    +cycler-0.11.0
    +cython-0.29.28
    +cytoolz-0.11.0
    +daal4py-2021.5.0
    +dal-2021.5.1
    +dask-2022.2.1
    +dask-core-2022.2.1
    +dataclasses-0.8
    +datashader-0.13.0
    +datashape-0.5.4
    +dbus-1.13.18
    +debugpy-1.5.1
    +decorator-5.1.1
    +defusedxml-0.7.1
    +diff-match-patch-20200713
    +distributed-2022.2.1
    +docutils-0.17.1
    +entrypoints-0.4
    +et_xmlfile-1.1.0
    +executing-0.8.3
    +expat-2.4.4
    +filelock-3.6.0
    +flake8-3.9.2
    +flask-1.1.2
    +fontconfig-2.13.1
    +fonttools-4.25.0
    +freetype-2.11.0
    +frozenlist-1.2.0
    +fsspec-2022.2.0
    +future-0.18.2
    +gensim-4.1.2
    +giflib-5.2.1
    +glib-2.69.1
    +glob2-0.7
    +gmp-6.2.1
    +gmpy2-2.1.2
    +google-api-core-1.25.1
    +google-auth-1.33.0
    +google-cloud-core-1.7.1
    +google-cloud-storage-1.31.0
    +google-crc32c-1.1.2
    +google-resumable-media-1.3.1
    +googleapis-common-protos-1.53.0
    +greenlet-1.1.1
    +grpcio-1.42.0
    +gst-plugins-base-1.14.0
    +gstreamer-1.14.0
    +h5py-3.6.0
    +hdf5-1.10.6
    +heapdict-1.0.1
    +holoviews-1.14.8
    +hvplot-0.7.3
 ...
```

EDIT:
I've uninstalled the following packages which cleaned up my environment quite a bit:
`conda uninstall jupyterlab matplotlib-inline notebook pillow statsmodels holoviews bokeh matplotlib dask datashader jupyter notebook seaborn xarray`

Comment: can use `pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y` to start fresh

Comment: is there a way to do this through conda? i don't know that all of these are python.

Comment: @capybara I was under the impression that conda clean removes the tar balls for installed packages.

Comment: This is too vague. Please define in the question what "non-essential" means. You have installed an Anaconda **base**, which means most of the packages can't be removed without removing the `anaconda` package. Were this me, I'd replace the whole installation with Mambaforge.

Comment: I should have specified, just enough to run "conda" and "anaconda" and nothing else. Then I can build my environment on additively.

Comment: What does "*run anaconda*" mean? As in the Anaconda Navigator GUI (`anaconda-navigator`)? Or uploading to Anaconda Cloud (`anaconda-client`)? Some people might think it includes Jupyter. One doesn't need the `anaconda` package (or distribution) for any of that.

Comment: So `anaconda -h` or `conda -h` doesn't fail. You're asking me to very specific but I think you understand what I'm asking in my initial question. The basic requirements for the conda software management suite to run without all of the bells and whistles like holoviews, datashaders, statsmodels, etc. Yes, I  agree that Jupyter isn't necessary to run conda. I can install that manually. Basically, I'm trying to streamline my compute environments on my linux server. I've updated the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

As for the `Mamba` installation issue, uninstalling Numpy solved the problem for me.

`conda uninstall numpy`
also uninstalled more than 100 packages that depend on it.
After that,

`conda install mamba -n base -c conda-forge`
worked like a breeze after that (about a minute)